# How to make Daredevil dripping wax using liquid simulation

Tags: animation, node-editor, physics, fluid-simulation

so i was wondering if anyone knows how to go about recreating the dripping wax effect as seen in the intro in the Daredevil show. 
Check out the intro: 
https://youtu.be/KFYFh8w4758 
 if anyone know i would be very interested to learn how 
thank you :)

Comment: Can you show us what you've got, or what you have tried so far and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

The effect is accomplished by using a hidden underlying mesh object to serve as a obstacle/attraction. This effect can be simulated by Blender's built-in fluid simulator, but could be easier and done more prettily with an add-on called FLIP Fluids. If this is just a personal/experimental project, you could go ahead and download it from their GitHub repository at https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids. If you're planning on selling it your work or sharing it with larger numbers of people, probably buy it from their Blender Market page.

Jeez I just realized how much that sounded like a sponsorship  
Anyway, I still think it's a valuable tool to be aware of.

Honestly, probably some in-depth fluid tutorials will teach you all you need to create this effect whichever method you choose. Take a look at this video, as a good starting point.  https://youtu.be/3o9E2t0cTCc

That will give you a basic overview of everything, then you can teaser h individual aspects a bit more closely.

I hope you get this working! Seems like an awesome project.

Comment: How to i attract the liquid or "wax" onto the shape. I am thinking of getting flip. It's on my list. it would be nice however, to be able to make the effect with out an external plug in.

Comment: Probably make a control (attraction) object inside the shape, and use the shape as a obstacle